# Apply function to dataframe row use result for next row input

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a rudimentary scheduling system. Here is what I have so far:

I have a pandas dataframe **job_data** that looks like this:

| wc | job | start | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J1 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 17 |
| 1 | J2 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 5 |
| 2 | J3 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 21 |
| 2 | J4 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 12 |

It contains a wc (work center), job, a start date and duration for the job in hours.

I have created a function **add_hours** that takes the following arguments: **start** (datetime), **hours** (int).

It calculates the when the job will be complete based on the **start** time and **duration**.

The code for **add_hours** is:

```
def is_in_open_hours(dt):
    return (
        dt.weekday() in business_hours["weekdays"]
        and dt.date() not in holidays
        and business_hours["from"].hour <= dt.time().hour < business_hours["to"].hour
    )


def get_next_open_datetime(dt):
    while True:
        dt = dt + timedelta(days=1)
        if dt.weekday() in business_hours["weekdays"] and dt.date() not in holidays:
            dt = datetime.combine(dt.date(), business_hours["from"])
            return dt


def add_hours(dt, hours):
    while hours != 0:
        if is_in_open_hours(dt):
            dt = dt + timedelta(hours=1)
            hours = hours - 1
        else:
            dt = get_next_open_datetime(dt)
    return dt
```

The code to calculate the **end** column is:

```
df["end"] = df.apply(lambda x: add_hours(x.start, x.duration), axis=1)
```

The result of function is the **end** column:

| wc | job | start | duration | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J1 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 17 | 2022-08-17 14:00:00 |
| 1 | J2 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 5 | 2022-08-17 10:00:00 |
| 2 | J3 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 21 | 2022-08-18 08:00:00 |
| 2 | J4 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 12 | 2022-08-18 08:00:00 |

Problem is, I need the **start** datetime in the second row to be the **end** datetime from the previous row instead of them all using the same start date. I also need to start this process over for each wc.

So the desired output would be:

| wc | job | start | duration | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J1 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 17 | 2022-08-17 14:00:00 |
| 1 | J2 | 2022-08-17 14:00:00 | 5 | 2022-08-17 19:00:00 |
| 2 | J3 | 2022-08-16 07:30:00 | 21 | 2022-08-18 08:00:00 |
| 2 | J4 | 2022-08-18 08:00:00 | 10 | 2022-08-18 18:00:00 |

Comment: What is the code of `add_hours`

Comment: I have edited my question to add the add_hours code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show an alternative method where you only need the `first start date` and then bootstrap the lists according to the job durations.

```py
# import required modules
import io
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# make a dataframe
# note: only the first start date is required
x = '''
wc  job start   duration    end
1   J1  2022-08-16 07:30:00 17  2022-08-17 14:00:00
1   J2  2022-08-16 07:30:00 5   2022-08-17 10:00:00
2   J3  2022-08-16 07:30:00 21  2022-08-18 08:00:00
2   J4  2022-08-16 07:30:00 12  2022-08-18 08:00:00
'''
data = io.StringIO(x)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\t')

# construct start and end lists
start = datetime.strptime(df['start'][0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
start_list = [start]
end_list = []
for x in df['duration']:
    time_change = timedelta(hours=float(x))
    new_time = start_list[-1] + time_change
    start_list.append(new_time)
    end_list.append(new_time)

start_list.pop(-1)

# add to dataframe
df['start'] = start_list
df['end'] = end_list

# finished
df
```

The result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Timedelta` and `groupby` operations.

As you did not provide your custom function, I'll apply here a simple addition of the duration:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])

t = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='h')
g = t.groupby(df['wc'])

df['start'] = df['start'].add(g.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(fill_value=pd.Timedelta('0'))))

df['end'] = df['start'].add(t)
```

Output:

```
   wc job               start  duration                 end
0   1  J1 2022-08-16 07:30:00        17 2022-08-17 00:30:00
1   1  J2 2022-08-17 00:30:00         5 2022-08-17 05:30:00
2   2  J3 2022-08-16 07:30:00        21 2022-08-17 04:30:00
3   2  J4 2022-08-17 04:30:00        12 2022-08-17 16:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the size of your dataset, but if it's not too big you could use the following elegant solution (which would take quite a while to run because your'e replicating calculations)

```
df['cum_duration'] = df.groupby('wc').duration.transform(sum)
df['end'] = df.apply(lambda x: add_hours(x.start, x.cum_duration), axis=1)
```

If the OP provides the `business_hours` df I could try to validate this solution